# how to fetch WordPress Data Base Table via Ruby script with dynamic active record classes?

Tags: ruby, wordpress

I currently have a website that is built in WordPress, and have over 1000 customers registered. Would I be able to extract the information from the **WordPress** db in ruby code

Need way that's seamless for my customers? Without requiring registering again?

Note:
**This code should create active record classes or models dynamically instead of manually defining active record models**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With out having the Gem You can achieve this via Ruby script itself

I assumed you have rails application from there you can create rake task to fetch the data from WordPress Database

**Step 1:**

```
value = {host: "192.*.*.*", username: '', password: '', database: ''}

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
      adapter: 'mysql2',
      encoding: 'utf8',
      pool: 5,
      host: value[:host],
      username: value[:username],
      password: value[:password],
      database: value[:database]
  )
```

**Step 2:**

Then Define the database tables needs to be fetched

```
database_tables = {:"database_name" =>  ["SaveContactForm7_1", "SaveContactForm7_2","SaveContactForm7_3","SaveContactForm7_4"]}
```

**Step 3:**

```
tables = database_tables[key]
Key refers to the database name
```

**Step 4:**

```
tables.each do |table|
    MODEL_CLASS= table
    Object.const_set(MODEL_CLASS, Class.new(ActiveRecord::Base) { def self.name() MODEL_CLASS end;def self.table_name() MODEL_CLASS end })
    records = MODEL_CLASS.constantize.all
    results = []
    records.each do |record|
      set = {}
      columns = MODEL_CLASS.constantize.column_names

       p columns

      columns.each do |column|
       p record.send(column.to_sym)
       p set[:mobile] = record.send(column.to_sym) 
      end

      results << set
      p record
    end

    p "Task done...."
    p results
  end
```

As a result you can see the array of hashes. you can insert into your active record models

Please Feel free to give your suggestion for this

Comment: Thanks for your immediate answer its helped me